# How can two forces be in the same direction AND be of the opposite sign?

Tags: electrostatics, terminology

In his book "Einstein's Theory of Relativity" (1962 edition) on page 147 Max Born wrote:

> "We next take two such test bodies P1 and P2, bring them in turn to the same point in the vicinity of M, and measure in each case the forces K1 and K2 as regards size and direction. We shall henceforth adopt the convention that opposite forces are to be regarded as being in the same direction and having opposite signs. Experiment shows that the two forces have the same direction but that their values may have different signs."

My questions are:

1. How can two forces be in the same direction AND be of the opposite sign?
2. What experiment "shows that the two forces have the same direction but that their values may have different signs?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, both questions are provoked by translation problems.

Concerning your question 1: In the original german version it reads “gleichgerichtet” which rather means same “alignment ” than same “direction”.

Concerning question 2: in the original, Born does not refer to any experiment but exactly to the Gedanken experiment he describes in the paragraphs above. The translation should thus be “This experiment reveals that...”

Comment: The English translation (proofread by Prof. Born's grandson John Pryce, a mathematician) also omits the prepositional phrase ,,in verschiedener Weise geriebene"...I wonder what else in the book got lost in translation and whether all technical books should be read in their authors' native language...

Answer (score 3):

A force of 5 N to the left is the same thing as a force of -5 N to the right.

Born is just choosing, when there are two forces opposing each other to say they are both pointing to the right but one is negative, rather than to say one is to the right and the other is to the left.

It doesn't change any of the physics, it's just a choice about how you describe things.